# Is "most everyone" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

*Everyone* is always singular.  *Most* can be either singular or plural depending on the subject which it describes.  *Most of everyone*, for example, would be singular since *everyone* is still the subject.  I don't know if it is the same if we remove the *of*, since now the subject is a group of individuals, not the individuals as a single whole.

> Most everyone **gets** to keep their money.

- or -

> Most everyone **get** to keep their money.

Comment: Please report what you found in a dictionary when you ask questions here.  My dictionary clearly says that "everybody"and "everyone" take singular verbs.

Comment: Which is what I stated in my first sentence.  I didn't know if the *most* modifier changed that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Most everyone" behaves the same as "everyone". "*Everyone* is always singular" is oversimplified.

As a subject, "everyone" and "most everyone" always take singular verb agreement in standard English, so "Most everyone gets..." is correct and *"Most everyone get" is incorrect.

As an antecedent, "everyone" can be coreferential with a plural pronoun, and other nouns in the sentence may be plural rather than singular. For example, you can find sentences like "Most everyone removed **their hats**," where the intended meaning is that each member of the group referred to by "most everyone" removed a single hat.

Comment: Note that _most_ is an American abbreviation for _almost_.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: Most everyone **gets**...

'Most everyone' means **almost everyone**. Everyone is singular. Most everyone/almost everyone is also singular. Everyone/almost everyone/most everyone takes a **singular** **verb**.

I would use **almost everyone** instead of 'most everyone'.